# Changing thread static value on dispose does not work with async

Tags: c#, .net-core

May be code starting with code will be easier to formulate question:

```
 public class RecorderScope : IDisposable
    {
        [ThreadStatic]
        private static RecorderScope current;

        public static RecorderScope Current => current;

        public RecorderScope()
        {        
            if (current != null) throw new Exception("usually by design, don't make complex stuff");
            current = this;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            current = null;
        }
    }
```

Meaning, that some other class might check if it is used within RecorderScope and do something with that fact. It is used in unit tests only, intended for simple cases, so I don't care about nesting, etc. - but unit tests might be executed in parallel, hence `[ThreadStatic]`.

Now it works fine as long as there's no await within that scope. I did some logging and looks like problem is that to constructor comes thread with id x and to dispose comes thread with id y (as expected, that's how async works), hence thread's x value remains not disposed.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: What test framework? For NUnit, use [TestContext](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestContext)

Comment: NUnit, I'll try to check if it would fit my scenario.

Comment: @canton7, I've checked TestContext's implementation, it also uses AsynLocal. Anyway, if you would turn your comment into answer, I would upvote it as alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now it works fine as long as there's no await within that scope... Any ideas how to fix it?

Yes. You really shouldn't use `ThreadStatic` at all in modern code. Use [`AsyncLocal<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.asynclocal-1) instead:

```
public class RecorderScope : IDisposable
{
  private static AsyncLocal<RecorderScope> current;

  public static RecorderScope Current => current.Value;

  public RecorderScope()
  {        
    if (Current != null) throw new Exception("usually by design, don't make complex stuff");
    Current.Value = this;
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    Current.Value = null;
  }
}
```

I have a [blog post](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html) that goes into more semantic details (written before `AsyncLocal<T>` existed).

The one important note that isn't well-documented with `AsyncLocal<T>` is that you should always update the value by setting the `Value` property - never by modifying the `T` object. Ideally, `T` should be immutable, but in this particular case (since `Value` is only set when `null`, and later set only to `null`, never updated), the immutability isn't necessary.

Comment: "shouldn't use ThreadStatic at all in modern code" seems like a pretty broad generalization. For context/scope, sure, but there are still completely valid use cases that AsyncLocal can't solve. ThreadStatic allows for writing synchronization / lock free code, eg. ArrayPool.Shared implementation.

Comment: `ArrayPool.Shared` is neither `ThreadStatic` nor lock-free, but you do have a good point. `Random.Shared` is a good example of modern code using `ThreadStatic`.

Comment: I was referring to the default shared pool itself (TlsOverPerCoreLockedStacksArrayPool) which uses small ThreadStatic buffers internally to reduce lock contention and larger processor specific buffers with locks.